# How to run a Cygwin program (xemacs) without showing a terminal window?

Tags: emacs, cygwin, emacsw32

The title pretty much sums it up - I like editing text with xemacs running under cygwin, and I'd prefer not to have it spawn a console window when I start it from a shortcut. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `run` command, in the `run` package, does exactly this:

```
c:\cygwin\bin\run.exe /usr/bin/xemacs
```

The console window may flash visible for a moment when you start Xemacs, but after that it will be hidden.

Comment: It works! (Note that it changes the shortcut icon, you will have to manually set the icon if it bothers you).