# Running a Cygwin Program from a Windows Shortcut

Tags: windows, cygwin, shortcuts, x11-forwarding, integration

I am attempting to set up my Windows 10 laptop with a few Linux programs using Cygwin and I'm not having much success.

My goal is to have shortcuts in my start menu that act just like native programs when you click on the icons.

I have Cygwin and Cygwin/X installed along with all of the programs and packages I'm looking to use and I can get programs like Gummi and XMGrace to run through the Cygwin bash terminal as expected. I have tried referencing these [two](http://thornton2.com/How_to_make_a_Windows_shortcut_that_runs_a_Cygwin_Bash_script_that_runs_X11_programs) [pages](https://superuser.com/questions/348716/how-to-run-a-cygwin-program-xemacs-without-showing-a-terminal-window) with no luck. The only result I get is a window (terminal I think) that flashes for a fraction of a second. I feel like there is a piece I'm missing.

Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: Have you started X Windows first before running Gummi and XMGrace?

Comment: As the applications as X ones, copy /etc/defaults/etc/X11/system.XWinrc as ~/.XWinrc and personalize the "menu apps"

Comment: @DavidPostill Yes, I have it set up to launch on startup, and I verified it was running before trying to launch a program. 

@matzeri I'm not sure what you are referencing, but I don't have `system.XWinrc` in my `/etc/defaults/etc/X11` directory.

Comment: By the way, the archived copy of Gummy for Windows can be downloaded from http://tinyurl.com/gummi-w32-unstable-5-exe

Answer (score 0):

I was trying to setup a windows shortcut that would directly run a Linux program (orpie) in Cygwin and was having the same issue (the terminal would flash up and then disappear).

The following worked for me:

c:\cygwin64\bin\run.exe /usr/bin/mintty  -l -e '/cygdrive/c/cygwin64/bin/orpie'

[image]